# CSPack-created package file is missing \siteroot folder

Tags: azure, iis, cspack

I am using `cspack` command to create `cspkg` as part of build. The command that I am using is

```
cspack.exe D:\StoreSimplePortal\StorSimple-Portal\src\StorSimple.CloudService\ServiceDefinition.csdef /out:StorSimple.CloudService.cspkg /role:StorSimpleExtension;D:\StoreSimplePortal\StorSimple-Portal\out\debug-AMD64\StorSimpleExtension /sitePhysicalDirectories:StorSimpleExtension;Web;D:\StoreSimplePortal\StorSimple-Portal\out\debug-AMD64\StorSimpleExtension /rolePropertiesFile:StorSimpleExtension;D:\StoreSimplePortal\StorSimple-Portal\src\StorSimple.CloudService\RoleProperties.txt
```

The build succeeds but **/sitesroot** folder is not created. Am I missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the sitesroot is in the StorSimpleExtension directory?  If it is not, verify that it is included in the .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to occur when the site physical directory parameter is too similar to the role path parameter.  Try altering the path parameter to:

```
/sitePhysicalDirectories:StorSimpleExtension;Web;D:\StoreSimplePortal\StorSimple-Portal\out\debug-AMD64\storSimpleExtension\
```

Note the added '\' and lowercase directory name.

See this question for more details:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/014ce124-5ca6-46ce-b1ea-3d677a092f65/azure-sdk-16-cspack-command-line-tool?forum=windowsazuredevelopment